# How to change the Domain in Facebook Share using meta tags?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sharing a page on Facebook. I am using Facebook meta tags to set image, title and description. Everything is fine but I need to change the domain name shown to Facebook. So, if  I am sharing sub.site.com I need to show site.com when a user share a product?

Comment: Have you tried `<meta property="og:url" content="LINK TO SITE.COM" />` ?

Comment: @sinisterfrog, yes not working